# Xamarin - styles not applied on the device

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I apologise if this seems very vague but I'm not sure how else to word it.
Styles that do not use the Xamarin environment for Android (Visual Studio 2015) have not been applied to my Samsung device (Android 4.1.2) as shown:
[image]

Structure of my axml file:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:weightSum="100"
    android:background="#FFF">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:paddingTop="50dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF" />
    <CheckBox
        android:text="CheckBox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:checked="true"
        style="@android:style/Widget.CompoundButton.CheckBox" />
    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button1" />
    <RadioButton
        android:text="RadioButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/radioButton1" />
    <ToggleButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/toggleButton1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

In Xamarin, I'm using the "Dialog Alert" theme with version 4.1.2 (V16) for Android. Where could I be going wrong or leaving something pending? I apologize if the indentation was not right because I am still learning.

Comment: Show us the definition of your style and where you apply it.

Comment: @Cheesebaron, this is my axml file with styles of my project:

[link](https://www.itextpad.com/FDzNm6tviR)

Comment: I dont understand your question then. You are not applying any styles that enforce old school Android styling. Android versions styling differ.